# Regular Expression: match word at start of sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I am wanting to match all occurrences of a certain word (in this case "Jill") that start a sentence in the middle of a paragraph.

"Hello sample string. Jill is great."

Now the expression `[.:?!]\sJill\b` will match this but matches at the position of the full stop. Is it possible to match at the start of the 'J' in "Jill"?

I'm using the c# flavour of regex.

Comment: I believe this is what the lookaheads are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I haven't tested it yet.
`(?<=[.:?!]\s)Jill\b`

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using grouping to capture Jill?

```
[.:?!]\s(Jill)\b
```

Comment: can you elaborate for this regex beginner

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx#GroupCollection

Comment: What grouping does is to capture what's between the parenthesis. But evpos answer using lookback is probably what you need.